# Extrair palavra com Regex (Entre strings duplicadas)

Tags: python, string, regex, parser

O problema é bem simples:

Preciso extrair apenas a primeira Data de nascimento(em negrito abaixo) de um texto que contém 2 palavras "LOCALDENASCIMENTO".
Porém, quando passo o regex, ele puxa tudo o que contém entre a primeira palavra e o **segundo** LOCALDENASCIMENTO (em negrito abaixo). Preciso puxar apenas até o **Primeiro**

```
        try:
            s = texto_sem_espaco
            #> ds = re.search("DATADENASCIMENTO:"(.*)"LOCALDENASCIM")
            ds = re.search("D\\s*A\\s*T\\s*A\\s*D\\s*E\\s*N\\s*A\\s*S\\s*C\\s*I\\s*M\\s*E\\s*N\\s*T\\s*O:(.*)L\\s*O\\s*C\\s*A\\s*L\\s*D\\s*E\\s*N\\s*A\\s*S\\s*C\\s*I\\s*M", s)
            ds = ds.group(1)
            print(ds)
        except:
            print("PG 7 NÃO ENCONTRADA")
```

**24/01/1986** **LOCALDENASCIMENTO:** ITANHEM-BANACIONALIDADE:BRASILEIROESTADOCIVIL:(X)SOLTEIRO()CASADO()VIÚVO()DIVORCIADOSEXO:(X)MASCULINO()FEMININONOMEDAEMPRESA:CNPJ:INSCRIÇÃOMUNICIPAL/ESTADUAL:CONTRIBUINTESIMPLES:()SIM()NÃOREPRESENTANTELEGAL:NOME:RG:DATADEEMISSAO:UFEMISSAO:ORGAOESXPEDIDOR:CPF:DATANASCIMENTO:**LOCALDENASCIMENTO**

Comment: existe algum motivo específico para utilizar regex?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, penso que o problema se da pelo regex utilizado e por selecionar o "grupo 1" na busca. Vou separar aqui em duas formas diferentes de fazer, mas existem muitas possibilidades.

---

**Primeira Forma**

O que você busca extrair é a data de nascimento que vem entre "DATADENASCIMENTO:" e a palavra "LOCALDENASCIMENTO:", podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

1. Primeiro precisamos encontrar a expressão para a busca (`re.search()`), recomendo utilizar um site de regex online. Eu utilizo o [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). Ao colocar o texto que você indicou, e começar procurando o regex que encontraria a data, achei uma seguinte solução: `(?i)DATADENASCIMENTO:(.*)LOCALDENASCIMENTO:`.

   - Onde: `(?i)` indica não se importar se é maiúsculo ou minúsculo (*case insensitive*).
   - O `DATADENASCIMENTO:(.*)LOCALDENASCIMENTO:` indica que vamos pegar qualquer coisa entre "datadenascimento:" e "localdenascimento:".

   > Vale dizer que não é a única solução e podemos achar outras formas de fazer isso (por exemplo usar Lookahead/Lookbehind). Além disso, como você só passou um exemplo, pode não funcionar para outros textos similares (por adição de algum caractere que o regex não considera).

2.Precisamos buscar no texto essa expressão e encontrar o grupo correto da busca. Eu utilizei o mesmo código que você passou (e mudei apenas alguns detalhes).

```
import re

texto_sem_espaco = "DATADENASCIMENTO:24/01/1986 LOCALDENASCIMENTO: ITANHEM-BANACIONALIDADE:BRASILEIROESTADOCIVIL:(X)SOLTEIRO()CASADO()VIÚVO()DIVORCIADOSEXO:(X)MASCULINO()FEMININONOMEDAEMPRESA:CNPJ:INSCRIÇÃOMUNICIPAL/ESTADUAL:CONTRIBUINTESIMPLES:()SIM()NÃOREPRESENTANTELEGAL:NOME:RG:DATADEEMISSAO:UFEMISSAO:ORGAOESXPEDIDOR:CPF:DATANASCIMENTO:LOCALDENASCIMENTO"

try:
    s = texto_sem_espaco
    ds = re.search("(?i)DATADENASCIMENTO:(.*)LOCALDENASCIMENTO:", s)
    data = ds.group(1)
    print(data)
except:
    print("PG 7 NÃO ENCONTRADA")
```

Final Output:
`24/01/1986`

---

**Segunda Forma**

O que você busca extrair é a data de nascimento que vem antes da palavra "LOCALDENASCIMENTO:", podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

1. No [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). Ao colocar o texto e ir procurando o regex que encontraria a data, achei uma seguinte solução: `(?i)[0-9\/\.]* ?localdenascimento:`.

   - Onde: `(?i)` indica não se importar se é maiúsculo ou minúsculo (*case insensitive*).
   - O `[0-9\/\.]*` indica que vamos pegar qualquer numero (com "\", ".", ou nada) que tiver a frente de um `localdenascimento:` separado ou não por espaço (definido pela parte " `?`").
2. Precisamos buscar no texto essa expressão e encontrar o grupo correto da busca. Eu utilizei o mesmo código que você passou (e mudei apenas alguns detalhes).

```
import re

texto_sem_espaco = "24/01/1986 LOCALDENASCIMENTO: ITANHEM-BANACIONALIDADE:BRASILEIROESTADOCIVI\
    L:(X)SOLTEIRO()CASADO()VIÚVO()DIVORCIADOSEXO:(X)MASCULINO()FEMININONOMEDAEMPRESA:CNPJ\
    :INSCRIÇÃOMUNICIPAL/ESTADUAL:CONTRIBUINTESIMPLES:()SIM()NÃOREPRESENTANTELEGAL:NOME:RG\
    :DATADEEMISSAO:UFEMISSAO:ORGAOESXPEDIDOR:CPF:DATANASCIMENTO:LOCALDENASCIMENTO"

try:
    s = texto_sem_espaco
    ds = re.search("(?i)[0-9\/\.]* ?localdenascimento:", s)
    data = ds.group(0)[:-19]
    print(data)
except:
    print("PG 7 NÃO ENCONTRADA")
```

3. Na parte `data = ds.group(0)[:-19]`, o `[:-19]` indica que estamos filtrando a string para remover o " LOCALDENASCIMENTO:" dado o retorno do ds.group(0) seria: `24/01/1986 LOCALDENASCIMENTO:`.

Final Output:
`24/01/1986`